# Visual Studio C++ MFC: Displaying bitmap from imagelist

Tags: c++, bitmap, mfc, imagelist

I have dialog with a picture control and I want to display an image of my imagelist. If I want to display a bitmap (no imagelist) by calling

```
CBitmap m_bmp;
m_bmp.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP);
m_picture.SetBitmap(m_bmp); //m_picuture is the member of the picture control
```

it works, but my imagelist fails.
Here's my code:

```
    m_bmparr.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAPARR); //bitmap is 144x48 (4 bit)
    m_imagelist.Create(48, 48, ILC_COLOR4, 0, 0); //3 * 48 = 144
    m_imagelist.Add(&m_bmparr, RGB(255, 0, 255));
    CBitmap* bitmap2;
    IMAGEINFO imgInfo;
    m_imagelist.GetImageInfo(1, &imgInfo); //Index 1 of imagelist
    bitmap2 = CBitmap::FromHandle(imgInfo.hbmImage);
    m_picture.SetBitmap(*bitmap2); //Show bitmap --> DOESN'T SHOW!! :(
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Is there any special reason you want to go through `CImageList`? You can set the bitmap directly, without `CImageList`. You can use icons if you need transparent background.

Comment: I need to work with an index. In general, it's more convenient to work with an index and only one bitmap file.

Comment: Your size doesn't really fit. You want a 144x48, but yet create the CImageList with 48x48.

Comment: Do you have to use an index and not explicitly a CImageList ? Wouldn't a STL container such as `std::vector` fit too ?

Comment: Are you sure with the length? I think when you create an imagelist, the first parameter is the length per picture. MS says: Dimensions of each image, in pixels. Yes, I have to use the imagelist and no stl container.

Comment: [`CImageList::Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9h1bwdk.aspx) - Dimensions of each image, in pixels. Width (cx) * Height (cy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create Image List from a large bitmap:

```
m_imagelist.Create(IDB_BITMAPARR, 48, 0, RGB(255, 0, 255))
```

Where icon width is 48, and bitmap width is 144 (or n * 48).

Use `ExtractIcon` to create a new icon. Index starts at zero, therefore use `ExtractIcon(0)` for first icon.

```
HICON hicon = m_imagelist.ExtractIcon(0);
ICONINFOEX iinfo;
iinfo.cbSize = sizeof(ICONINFOEX);
GetIconInfoEx(hicon, &iinfo);

m_picture.SetBitmap(iinfo.hbmColor);
//destroy hicon when finished
```